# Insert and Select Last Value in Sql

Tags: c#, sql

I want to insert the last customer id in child table but the below code inserting all the data

```
public void insertCustomer(int eqpId)
    {
        con = new Connection2DB();
        con.sqlquery("insert into Customer_Equipment(Cst_ID,EquipId) values ((Select Max(Cst_ID) from Customer),'"+eqpId+"')");

        con.NonQueryEx();
    }
```

Comment: can you tag the database being used?

Comment: why you are not using Identity column features?

Comment: @Talha your question is very vague. Why do you need the "last" ID to insert? What do you mean last? Largest value? Or the last value inserted by *your* code?

Comment: @Talha For the last inserted record you should use identity column feature.

Comment: @Talha perhaps you should check how the iNSERT statement works before trying to execute a query from C#?  And try it with a query tool, eg SSMS for SQL Server? If you want to insert a query's results you use `INSERT ... SELECT`, not `INSERT VALUES`. The way it's written it will throw syntax erros. Try to get the query working first, *then* look for ways to call it from C#

Comment: Where is your "Where" clause?

Comment: @Talha How do you know the last id value is largest value because you are using the "MAX"? What about adding another column like CREA_DATE (Created date) in customer table. When insert the data into customer table, you also need to insert the current_timestamp into CREA_DATE column. So that you can know the last id by selecting like "SELECT CST_ID FROM Customers ORDER BY CREA_DATE DESC LIMIT 1".

Comment: Customer Id is autogenerated

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)
```

Here is your modified query.

```
con.sqlquery("insert into Customer_Equipment(Cst_ID,EquipId) values ((SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘Customer’)),'"+eqpId+"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(columns....)
VALUES(..........)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- this is it
```

so you can use it somehow like

```
public void insertCustomer(int eqpId)
{
    con = new Connection2DB();
    con.sqlquery("insert into Customer_Equipment(Cst_ID,EquipId) values (SCOPE_IDENTITY(),'"+eqpId+"')");

    con.NonQueryEx();
}
```

There are also two more other possibilities like `@@IDENTITY` and `IDENT_CURRENT`. Each behaves little differently.

Comment: BTW: you should use sql parameter in your queries instead of the direct using of a variable. e.g. `insert into Customer_Equipment(Cst_ID,EquipId) values (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @eqpId)`

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`UPDATE` statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Try something like this:

```
`    
"UPDATE Customer_Equipment
SET EquipId = " + eqpId + "
WHERE Cst_ID = (Select Max(Cst_ID) from Customer)
`
```

Not really sure if this is 100% accurate, but hope you get the idea.

Also, to improve code style, I recommend you to check out [string interpolation in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: But it will insert only eqpId i want equipmentId and CustomerId both in child table

Comment: Interpolation is no improvement. It's as bad as string concatenation when constructing queries, fully exposing the code to SQL Injection attacks and conversion problems. The real improvement would be to use parameterized queries

Comment: @Talha It will actually update the eqpID for the last Customer.

Comment: BTW `MAX(Cst_ID)` won't return the parent's ID, unless *nobody else* uses that database. Even then, it can return the *wrong* ID if there are deletions.